# Change javascript validation on form to onblur or onchange instead of submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form that validates php and javascript.

I would like to change the javascript validation to real time. I have it setup so classes and messages are added if user enters proper information or incorrect information after clicking the submit button. This is a validation I have used for awhile and would like to update to be a live validation. I have tried to add onblur(myFunction) etc to the input fields with a corresponding function. That does not seem to work. I am a javascript noob. I realize the script will need quite a bit of overhaul, however can someone point me in the right direction. I realize there is a jquery plugin that does some of this, however I would like to learn how its happening rather than using an existing code.

```
        $(function () {
        $('#contact_form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            var post_url = form.attr('action');
            var post_data = form.serialize();
            var submit_form = false;

            *validation here*

            if (pcount == 0 && pcount2 == 0 && pcount3 == 0) {
                submit_form = true;
            }

            if (submit_form) {
                $('#loader', form).html('<img src="assets/img/loader.gif" /> Please Wait...');
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : post_url,
                    data : post_data,
                    success : function(msg) {
                        $(form).fadeOut(500, function() {
                            form.html(msg).fadeIn();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so hard to do, just separate the sending and the validation like this:

```
$.fn.validateMyForm = function() {
    var form = $(this);
    /* validation */
    if (pcount == 0 && pcount2 == 0 && pcount3 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$(function () {
    $('#contact_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var post_url = form.attr('action');
        var post_data = form.serialize();
        if ($(form).validateMyForm()) {
            /* ajax sending */
        });
    }
});
```

And then add the validation on the blur events where needed:

```
$("input").blur({
    $('#contact_form').validateMyForm();
});
```

Comment: Should i put those in individual .js files or can they all go in one? Also do i have to call a class on the blur. ("input.name").blur? Or will the original *var verify_field = $('input[rel=check]');* work without it going to post.

Comment: They can go in one file, there is no problem with that, and you may call the validate on the form for any element's blur event.

Comment: Right on. I have gotten the validation to work perfect with the changes you specified. I had to add a function() to $("input").blur(right here{ to make it work. However with the second function in the file the validation quits. Should i be adding a document ready there or something?

Comment: add the blur event handlers into the ready block too, where you defined the submit event handler for the form